# Can you link directly to a new copy of a Google Docs or Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to craft a URL (or bookmarklet) so that when clicked it opens a fresh "copy" of an existing Google Docs or Sheets?

Apparently it *used* to be possible by appending **`&newcopy=true`** to the end of the URL, but this doesn't appear to work any longer.

Is there a new method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change `/edit` in the end of the link to `/copy`.

Before:

```
... B3iw8gTpKwAW8/edit
```

After:

```
... B3iw8gTpKwAW8/copy
```

Comment: Add more details like the /copy URL will take the user to a page asking to confirm that the user want to create a copy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a supported way to handle this or not, but I was able to get this to work with a little hackery.

From the Google Doc that you want to make the copy link for:

- Click the *File* drop down
- Click the **Make a copy...** option
- Click the **OK** button
- When the new window pops up, quickly copy the initial URL *before* it redirects to the copied document. This is the link you want.

From there, I removed the `&token` URL parameter, and the rest should be self explanatory and can be adjusted as necessary: `&copyComments`, `&copyCollaborators`, and `&title`.

Obviously, the user who is trying to make the copy needs the appropriate privileges in the sheet to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it should work in this way in new sheets!

`Goto Share` then, get `Share able Link`. Using the link, you can customize and get that a non-editable/comment able. Then the shared user can create a copy of it/new sheet with the copy.

I understand this may not be the real use case we're using previously. However, it helps me at times.

Answer (score -1):

All i did was /copy instead of /edit :)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This was [already mentioned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79381/88163) 6 years ago.